# C# String Replace not removing String from End

Tags: c#, string

I working on Natural Language Processing, I am trying to remove *last part* of string, but it remove string from *inside* a string,
my code.

```
public string RemoveSuffix(string word)
{
  if (word.EndsWith("ی")
  { 
    word = word.Replace("ی","");
  }

  return word;
}
```

Comment: What is the given input, how do you mean it does not work

Comment: String replace function replace all occurrence of sub string what you provide, you should use remove method of string

Comment: `word=word.Replace("ی","");` would replace all occurrences not only the suffix.

Comment: `Replace` does exactly what it says - it replaces this string, no matter where it's found. Why should it replace only the *last* occurence?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, this code works for me. Could it be that the language this is in is *Right to Left* and you actually need to trim the start? Please provide a [mcve] to clarify.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer the OP says `Replace` removes the character from any position, not just the end. Just as it should

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oooh. Thanks for clarifying. I thought he meant the replace works except when he checks with `EndsWith`, my bad.

Answer (score 4):

You, probably, are looking for [TrimEnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  // static: you have no need in "this"
  public static string RemoveSuffix(string word) {
    return word == null // <- do not forget to validate public method's argument(s)
      ? null            // or throw ArgumentNullException      
      : word.TrimEnd('ی'); 
  }
```

Comment: Could be also wrote as: `public string RemoveSuffix(string word) => word?.TrimEnd('ی') ?? null;`

Comment: @GiulioCaccin what's the point of `?? null`? Did you want to write `?? ""` perhaps?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos just to keep the semantics and the comments the original author wrote ^_^  
It's better with the empty string, i'll update.

Comment: @GiulioCaccin then I repeat, what's the point of `?? null`? Read what you typed again. `??` will only work if the left-hand value is `null`. And then it will return ... null. Might as well remove it altogether

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i know, it was to keep semantics without providing another answer.

Comment: @GiulioCaccin But it does not make sense, ?? means if null so you have if null return null....

Comment: In the spirit of wisecracking, an exception throwing expression bodied function could be `RemoveSuffix(string word) => word?.TrimEnd('ی') ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(word))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it was exactly the kind of stuff i was pointing to. It's also working with `?? null`

Comment: @GiulioCaccin For the last time, your `?? null` is nonsense (just trying to help you understand `??`). You can just leave that whole part out. its like: return null but if returning value is null return null instead... which is nonsense

Answer (score -2):

you should have to try

```
public string RemoveSuffix(string word,string lstPart)
{
 return  word=word.TrimEnd(lstPart);

}
```

you can change your hard code word with a variable/List Item

Comment: `String` has many methods that can help, including trimming methods. No need to write all this. Not my downvote, but this answer should be deleted

Comment: @Edward Islam thanks this work prefect now i can call this method for all post fixes ,

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Method name "RemoveSuffix" make sence to NLP researcher.